# ngRoute TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I have written this small sample for ngRoute

http://plnkr.co/edit/bJOai9XVGJcsA9zOriUN?p=preview

But it will keep failing with TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I have searched the web and the suggestions are not working for me. any ideas why it does not like ngRoute?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Foo">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

### script.js

```
var app = angular.module('Foo', ['ngRoute']);
app.configure(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'foo.html',
      controller: 'FooCtrl'
    })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the function is `config()`, not `configure()`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module

Also, you shouldn't use ngRoute 1.2.20 with angular 1.2.23. Make sure the versions are identical.